# Create functions dynamically or programmatically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dynamic, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to create functions dynamically on the fly or to create functions programmatically in python and am getting stuck at this.

```
def test(a,b):
    print(a)

#Result:
def test(a,b,c):
    print(a)
    print(b,c)
```

I am trying it with AST module and failing to understand the AST syntax for function. I understand that a function details can be fetched using functionname.__code__.xxx. But I will be unable to make changes since it is readonly. Here is what I am trying:

- I tried getting the AST dump of the above function and it didnt work.
- Trying to get the string version of function definition (couldnt find reference)

I have also tried the below but feel that it may be an issue somewhere like when there is a re-assignation which makes it local:

```
def tests(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    def mytest(c):
        print(a,b,c)
    return mytest

def tests(a,b):
    print(a,b)
    def mytest(c):
        print(a,b,c)
        a = 10 # this will become local variable
    return mytest
```

I am on python 3.x

Any help or any other easier way?

Comment: [x,y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/377931) ?

Comment: ok help me edit it. cant think of simpler explanation actually. Multiple results is known. cant help it. had to explain was was done.